# Pillow ImageEnhance Brightness and Contrast: what is the best order to apply these two filters?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, image-enhancement

Looking at the Brightness and Contrast classes in ImageEnhance:

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageEnhance.html

The image is in RGB mode, 8 bits per channel.

I could apply Brightness first, then Contrast to the same image. Or I could choose the opposite order.

Does it make a difference? If it does, is there a recommended order?

Would the recommendation change if the image was in L mode, 8 bits per pixel?

Comment: Personally I tend to avoid all of the *enhance* methods because I find it difficult to guess what parameters might be useful and all a bit arbitrary. They are ok if you are writing a GUI and you provide sliders allowing interactive users to *"tweak"* the look of an image.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Tweaking the image in an exploratory way is exactly what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: If you want to experiment and tweak images interactively, maybe look at https://www.photopea.com/ and ImageJ here https://ij.imjoy.io/

Answer (score 1):

it depends on what you want to achieve. If you need to enhance the details then **contrast** first. If you need brightness overall then **brightness** first.
According to docs **brightness** it'll make all pixels brighter/darker.  **Contrast** will make the bright pixels brighter and the dark pixels darker, but middle gray values will keep unchanged.